# Edit commit message after squashing

Tags: git, rebase, git-commit, git-squash

I want to implement featureX and I have committed it after writing it by

```
git commit -m "featureX"
```

After that I have done some changes and committed by

```
git commit -m "yo1"
```

squashed the commit by

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

again some changes and committed by

```
git commit -m "yo1"
```

squashed the commit by

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Now git log shows -

```
featureX
yo1
yo2
```

I want to change commit message yo1 and yo2 to change1 and change2.

Also, I want to know that how can I see the changes that I have done in yo1 and yo2 because I have forgot what changes I have done in yo1 and yo2.

Answer (score 5):

Squashing commit means generating a new hash id for your commit and merging your commit changes in one single commit. All the information in your commit tree regarding commits with commit messages yo1 and yo2 are lost now(merged in featureX).

However you can still see them if you know their commit hash id and also given that git haven't been through garbage collection. They would still be there lying detached from your branch as an object.

Do **git reflog** to find out the hash id associated with your commit message (yo1 or yo2).

Then you can simply **git show hashid#** to see the commit change you made there.

If you just simply want to change the commit message, it is much simpler and can be accomplished by either doing

**git commit --amend**

or

**git rebase -i HEAD~1** (-i stands for interactive mode)

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
git commit --amend -m "New commit message"
```

To amend the most recent commit, since a squash commit is a *all-in-one* squashed commit.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot know the original changes since squash combine all commits into one. It makes a new commit

You Can change commit description with an `amend` on last commit or an `interactive rebase` and edit option

```
Git commit --amend
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to edit that HEAD (current commit) you can use the

```
git commit --amend
```

> Also, I want to know that how can I see the changes that I have done in yo1 and yo2

In order to see the content of the latest commit and update it

```
git commit --amend --verbose
```

[image]
In order to see content of a given commit you can use

```
git show <sha-1>
```

[image]